Is there any way to use Apollo Federation with HotChocolate to make one to many relationships between entities located in different services?
I have PostService and UserService in two different web applications written on c# web api. There is also an Apollo api gateway.
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList: [
        { name: 'user', url: 'http://localhost:5250/graphql' },
        { name: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:5100/graphql' },
    ],
});

I want to create supergraph and use such queries:
{
  getUser(id: 1) {
    id
    name
    email
    posts {
      id
      title
      content
    }
  }
}

PostService and UserService have no dependencies between each other except contract types User and Post.
I don't want to create direct http calls between these two services like:
        public User GetUser([Parent] Post post, [Service] IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("userService");
            var response = client.GetAsync($"/user/{post.UserId}").Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>().Result;
        }

Could I do this logic using Apollo somehow? Maybe type extensions? I want Apollo gateway to resolve that posts for specific user should be taken from PostService.
